# Why does my variable only return one value outside of a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables

Apologies if this is obvious, but my function creates a list. Printing the variable of the list, inside the function returns all the list. But printing the global variable outside the function only returns the first value? Here are the two different versions of the code:

Printing inside the formula works:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

noise_1 = "somerandomvalue"

min_var_length = 8
max_var_length = 16

#creates a powerset of the input value, taking into account min and max lengths
def powerset(iterable):
    global powerset_list
    s = list(iterable)
    x = list(chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1)))
    x_string = list(x)
    for items in x_string:
        if len(items) > min_var_length:
                powerset_list = items
                print(powerset_list)


powerset(noise_1)
```

And returns a powerset of noise_1

However this code returns only one value, even though I am printing the same global variable:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

noise_1 = "somerandomvalue"

min_var_length = 8
max_var_length = 16

#creates a powerset of the input value, taking into account min and max lengths
def powerset(iterable):
    global powerset_list
    s = list(iterable)
    x = list(chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1)))
    x_string = list(x)
    for items in x_string:
        if len(items) > min_var_length:
                powerset_list = items



powerset(noise_1)
print(powerset_list)
```

I'm guessing it's terminating the function after one value, but I don't know how to change this behaviour. Thank you for your help! Sorry I r noob.

Comment: You are ***replacing*** the entire list with `items`; you're not appending to the list. From there the difference is simply whether you're also printing that one-item "list" on each loop iteration, or once at the end.

Comment: I understand. So to solve it I can basically just append to the powerset list i.e. powerset_list = [ ]  and then powerset_list.append(items)

Answer (score 0):

So to confirm, appending to the list after the for loop creates the list of all of the items. The print command in the function just prints the for loop as they occur, but only one item is saved in the variable.